# LINQ query to find objects in list with equal values for one of their properties

Tags: c#, linq, loops

I am iterating through a list and looking for objects that have the same value for one of their properties. I need an IEnumerable of the unique values of the properties that overlap.

This was my original nested loop solution.

```cs
List<Event> eventsWithDatetimeCollisions = new List<Event>();
for (int i = 0; i < eventList.Count; i++)
{
    Event event1 = eventList[i];

    for (int j = i + 1; j < eventList.Count; j++) // for each event after event1 in the list
    {
        Event event2 = eventList[j];
    
        if (DateTime.Compare(event1.EventDateTime, event2.EventDateTime) == 0)
            eventsWithDatetimeCollisions.Add(event1);
    }
}
```

@NetMage pointed out a bug in my loop solution that if there are 3 events with the same time, the first will be added to the list twice and the second will be added once. A similar problem exists with my LINQ solution.

I came up with the following query that almost gives me the results I want but it has some duplicate values and I am wondering if it could be written better. I am manually checking that the events aren't the same, is there a way to avoid this? As I understand it, this query will compare every event to each event in the list including itself which results in a lot of extra comparisons.

```cs
var dateTimeCollisions = from event1 in eventList
                         from event2 in eventList
                         where event1 != event2   // I want to avoid this bit 
                               && DateTime.Compare(event1.EventDateTime, event2.EventDateTime) == 0
                         select event1;
```

This isn't something that needs to be optimized for speed, most of the time the list has less than 5 items in it and it's not getting executed regularly or at short intervals, I was just curious if there is a better way (more efficient, easier to read / write, etc).

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it? Looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Please write your question in the title. The title is asking something completely different.

Comment: The more important question is what are you trying to accomplish? Do you simply want to filter out the objects in the list where `DateTime` property has the same value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GroupBy might be a better option here - a bit more memory but much lower complexity.

```
eventList.GroupBy(x => x.EventDateTime).Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
```

Each group's key is the collision datetime, and value is the events which collide on that time.

Adding `.Select(g => g.Key)` will give you just the datetimes.

Comment: P.S. Performance wise might not be different given your data size, but at least much simpler code IMHO.

Comment: Never thought of using group by like that. Very useful, thank you!

Comment: I ended up refining the question slightly and you might want to modify your answer to reflect the change. I only need the unique datetime values so I just added a select clause to the end of your query.  `eventList.GroupBy(e => e.EventDateTime).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.Key);`

Answer (score 1):

This will collect the first entry in `eventList` that has an equal `EventDateTime` later in the list.

```
var eventsWithDatetimeCollisions = eventList.GroupBy(e => e.EventDateTime)
                                            .Where(eg => eg.Count() > 1)
                                            .Select(eg => eg.First())
                                            .ToList();
```

Comment: "if three events have a match, you will keep the first one twice and the second one, but not the third one" - that was a bug that I didn't notice in the original implementation. I actually only need one instance of each colliding datetime, I don't need the event objects themselves. sidecus's answer gives me the results I want, but I realize now how my question could have been more clear.

Comment: @JacobHuckins Ah, updated my answer to keep the first of each group.